# Synchronous code in the asynchronous @RabbitListener?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, rabbitmq, amqp

From the RabbitMQ docs, a message is received asynchronously using `@RabbitListener` endpoint:

`"The easiest way to receive a message asynchronously is to use the annotated listener endpoint infrastructure. In a nutshell, it allows you to expose a method of a managed bean as a Rabbit listener endpoint."`

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
public void processOrder(String data) {
    ...
}
```

What does receiving asynchronously mean here exactly? What is the effect of using blocking calls, e.g. synchronous HTTP inside of the `processOrder(...)` function above, given the definition of `receiving asynchronously`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asynchronously mean here that you don't invoke that method directly, instead, some background service will call it at some moment of time which is not controlled by you. On which thread this method will be called, depends on configuration of that service. Usually such services use a thread pool.

The effect of using blocking calls inside asynchronous methods is the thread the method runs on is blocked and cannot serve other asynchronous invocations. If the thread pool behind the asynchronous service has limited number of threads, then so called "thread starvation" may happen and new asynchronous calls cannot be processed. Otherwise, if the thread pool is unlimited, it could consume all available memory because each thread requires 0.5-1 MB for its call stack. To avoid such negative consequences, the asynchronous service must be constructed with throughput high enough to bear expected load, and in case of heavy load, precautions should be taken for the service to degrade gracefully and not crash the whole JVM with OOM.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "thread starvation"? When this happens, what kind of behaviour can I expect? An exception or something else?

Comment: @pewewi this means that an asynchronous procedure, for example "processOrder()", becomes ready because a message arrived, but cannot start because of absence of available threads in thread pool - they all are blocked. In case they are blocked waiting the result of the very "processOrder()" method, this is a kind of deadlock and all the program hangs forever.

Comment: What would be the effects of e.g. using a `CompletableFuture` as wrapper to the blocking call, given that the `@RabbitListener` is asynchronous already? I have a related question of having synchronous HTTP in `@RabbitListener` if you could be so kind to take a look.

Comment: @Zeruno the effects of using a CompletableFuture as wrapper to the blocking call are exactly the same as of using RabbitListener, as both are kinds of asynchronous procedure calls.

Comment: In other words, can one say that the CompletableFuture, wrapped in @RabbitListener, does not provide any effect?

Comment: @Zeruno depends on how exactly CompletableFuture is wrapped in RabbitListener. Most likely, there will be a small overhead and increased latency.

Comment: So you are saying that one can expect an overhead rather an improved performance by using CompletableFuture in @RabbitListener? Is this correct? It is quite an eye-opener for me if so.

Comment: @Zeruno how can you expect to improve performance with an additional wrapper? That wrapper inevitably consumes some additional resources (CPU time and memory).